# i am trying to add space between the output, what i do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

this is output

> 

```
 input: Ahsu Basu
 output: bASUaHSU
 Desired Output: bASU aHSU
```

please help me to solve this. 
Thanks
this is the code

```
import re
a = input()
a = a.split()
a = list(reversed(a))
a = ''.join(map(str, a))
a = a.swapcase()
a = re.sub("([A-Z])", " \\1", a)
print(a)
```

Comment: a = ' '.join(map(str, a)) add space inside the join

Comment: Start by understanding the role of the `str` object that invokes the method.

Comment: The code boils down to `' '.join(reversed(text.split())).swapcase()`

Comment: @Matthias haha. Yes. The pythonic way.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ' '.join(map(str, a))
```

add white space inside the join

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
import re
a = input()
a = a.split(" ")
a = list(reversed(a))
a = ' '.join(a)
a = a.swapcase()
print(a)
```

Output

```
bASU aHSU
```

The `map(str, a)` and `re.sub("([A-Z])", " \\1", a)` is unnecessary in your case.